# Problems with knitting .Rnw file

Tags: r, knitr

I had to setup a new computer and used `Ubuntu 14.04` as the running system. I followed all instructions which worked well in the past.

The problem is related to `knit2pdf`. In `Rstudio` when compiling `.Rnw` via `library(knitr)` with either `pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX` everything works fine. So for example [yihui Beamer .Rnw](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-beamer.Rnw) is compiled without any issues to PDF. Using `knit2pdf` produces the following errors:

```
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'Beamer.tex' failed.
Messages:
tar: Beamer.aux: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: Beamer.nav: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: Beamer.out: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: Beamer.toc: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
```

I tried to figure out the problem and followed some instructions without success:

I reinstalled `Ubuntu` and tried different things

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full 

sudo apt-get install texinfo
```

Here as some details to my computer:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8       
  [4] LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                           LC_ADDRESS=C              
 [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8      LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
 [1] rmarkdown_0.9.2 ggplot2_2.0.0   stringi_1.0-1   reshape_0.8.5       reshape2_1.4.1  knitr_1.12.3   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] Rcpp_0.12.3      digest_0.6.9     grid_3.2.3       plyr_1.8.3           gtable_0.1.2     formatR_1.2.1   
 [7] magrittr_1.5     evaluate_0.8     scales_0.3.0     highr_0.5.1          labeling_0.3     tools_3.2.3     
[13] stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.2    colorspace_1.2-6 htmltools_0.3
```

Comment: Looks rather like a permission issue on your system than like a problem with `knitr`. You could try `texi2dvi` on a command line to check if this fails too. Is the RNW file in a TAR archive?

Comment: I'm so sorry. You are right. After `sudo Rscript` the pdf has been created. Thank you! Do you have an idea why I cant execute within R Studio? I created all relevant directories using `sudo mkdir...` also in the past without any issues. Do you want to "Answer the question" to get the confirmation?

Comment: No, I don't want to answer. As someone who doesn't use linux I can only guess what is happening. If you think you can provide an answer that will be helpful for future visitors, then you could self-answer your question and accept your own answer. If you don't think that this may be helpful in the future, you could consider deleting your question.